# Markerclusterer for google map api load problem

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer

A cluster of several is not displayed, it does not appear when you do an interaction with the map, the case is generated only on clusters that contains a lot of markers <=> > 150 marker.

> It's about indicate starting points of carpool solution.

[the first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPIae.png)

[After interaction example of interaction : zoom in, zoom out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvjB7.png)

```
{% block scripts  %}
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{myKey}}"> 
    </script>

    {% javascripts
     'bundles/myFirstBundle/scripts/markerclusterer.min.js'
     'bundles/myFirstBundle/scripts/myMapCodes.js'
    %}
      <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>

    {% endjavascripts %}

    <script>
        var locations = functionGetLocalisationsFromTheBackOffice();
        initMap(locations);
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Always in the first load the marker clusters are missing.

```
var markers = [];

var cluStyles = [
    {
        textColor: 'white',
        url: 'icons/clustererIco.png',
        height: 53,
        width: 35
    }
];
var clustersStyles = {
    styles: cluStyles 
};



    function initMap(locations) {
        markers = locations.map(function (loca, e) {
            position = {lat: loca.lat, lng: loca.lng};
            return new google.maps.Marker({
                position: 
                id : location.carId,
                position,
                icon: {
                    url: location.ico,
                    labelOrigin: new google.maps.Point(2, 2)
                },
                label: {
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                }
            });
        });
    markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clustersStyles);
    }
```

tried solution :

```
setTimeout(function () {
            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
        }, 1000);
```

but it will not work when markers exceed 150.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does the code that is served to the client look like?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: an example is provided, thanks for your help.

Comment: What does the `locations` array look like? Are you sure it isn't a data problem? Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: no problem in data, is js loading problem, with setTimeout it will work for < 1000 marker, for > 1000 will not, please see the the pics : 
the first load

After interaction example of interaction : zoom in, zoom out

Comment: Pictures don't help debug your code.

Comment: I'm intressting also, please help us

Comment: the problem is here : 
  do not load all markers :
 markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clustersStyles);

tried solution :
work only if we have 1000 markers
setTimeout(function () {
            markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
        }, 1000);
so am asking for some generic solution.

Comment: Sounds like a timing problem.  You should wait for the data to complete loading before using it to create the MarkerClusterer (setTimeout is not a good way to do that).  How are you loading the data?

Comment: yes it is a problem of loading time, I do not know the amount of data in advance, so I have to set up a system of promises or callback, and MarkerClusterer belongs to a plugin markerClusterer.js

do you have an idea how to solve the problem only by changing the setTimeOut ??